# How to use post_class function?

Tags: post-class

I would like to use this function, but I don't know correctly what is the perfect way..

The code:

```
<li  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(get_the_content() == "" ? "no-content" : ""); ?> <?php post_class(has_post_thumbnail() ? "" : "no-image"); ?>>
```

There are two if statements. Currently only the first working, the second not but if I remove the first `<?php post_class(get_the_content() == "" ? "no-content" : ""); ?>` the second working. How can in combine these lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`post_class` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters) to test multiple conditions:

```
function wpa_post_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if( ! has_post_thumbnail() ) $classes[] = "no-image";
    if( get_the_content() == "" ) $classes[] = "no-content";
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpa_post_class' );
```

Then your html will just be:

```
<li  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Thank you, just one question. Is it possible to use this function in the template file like my code above?

Comment: If your theme has a *functions.php* file, that's where the top snippet ought to go. The latter you can use in your template file. +1